# Sometimes and Present Perfect

Tags: present-perfect

I have 2 sentences:

"I sometimes forget to put my phone into my pocket. Therefore, I do not have GPS to navigate my way" (1)
and

"I have forgotten to put my phone into my pocket many times. Therefore, I didnot have GPS to navigate my way" (2)

Which one is correct?

Thank you.

Sorry because my question is not clear

Comment: *Forget* is present tense; *have forgotten* is present perfect.  Both sentences are grammatical.  What is confusing you?

Comment: Hi deadrat. I am confused about the meaning of (1) and (2) whether they are interchangeable?  I wanna say "i have forgotten to put my phone into my pocket in many times. Therefore, I did not have GPS to navigate my way."

Comment: When you use a present tense, it implies you have the habit of forgetting". If you use a present perfect, it doesn't have such a connotation and emphasizes the fact that it happened many times. If you want to emphasize you had the habit in the past, you say "I used to forget..." which is quite different construction.

Comment: So, if I use (1), the meaning is my habit which will happen in future. But if I use present perfect (2), so this implies a complete action but at some point in the past. Am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're both grammatical; they just mean slightly different things.

> I sometimes forget to put my phone into my pocket

uses what's called the enduring present tense.  It describes an ongoing situation.  You've forgotten your phone in the past, and you're likely to continue to do that.  It's the answer to the question, "Will you be able to find my apartment building using GPS?"  Alas, likely not, because of your ongoing habit of forgetting your GPS-enabled phone.

> I have forgotten to put my phone into my pocket many times

uses the present perfect, which, as you noted, describes events from some time past up to the present moment.  It's the answer to the question, "Why have you on occasion been unable to find my apartment building with GPS?"

The reason that the difference in meaning is slight is that we all know that forgetfulness can be a habit, which the phrase "many times" re-enforces.  That's a semantic issue, which blurs the difference in syntax.

Comment: Thanks deadrat. Your comment is quite useful. My problem here may be that I do not think about the meaning of the sentence. If I want to talk about a habit/ an illness, I must use sometimes. But if I talk about the past but at undefined occasions, "have forgotten" is the choice. However, admittedly, it is quite confusing.

Comment: @LearningEnglish There's an idiomatic use "I forget," which means that something has slipped your mind as you try to recall it right now.  So let's use another verb.  If someone asks, "What do you do for exercise?" a proper answer is "I swim."  Enduring present tense:  it's your habit to swim for exercise, it has been for some time, and you expect to continue to swim for exercise.  There's no need to add *sometimes*.  That's implied by the tense in this context.  Yes, it's quite confusing.  I'm sure I couldn't learn English if I hadn't grown up with it.

Comment: Cool. Thanks deadrat very much. I am so happy because you are able to point out one of my problems that have been answered before. ^^.